# Deploying Application Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I trying out kubernetes and have been trying to deploy a simple tomcat image

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: simple-hello
  labels:
    app: hello-tomcat
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-tomcat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-tomcat
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: helloworld
        image: tomcat:8.0.52-jre8
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
```

After the deployment, I simply expose it

> kubectl expose deployment simple-hello --type=LoadBalancer
>   --name=my-service

I have also tried

> kubectl expose deployment simple-hello --type=LoadBalancer
>   --name=my-service --port 80 --target-port 8080

I see the pods are up and I get the URL as well but when I try to hit the URL I don't get any response.

The my-service output description is as follows

```
Name:                     my-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=hello-tomcat
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=hello-tomcat
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       100.64.42.168
LoadBalancer Ingress:     a5c67f4526eb811e881a24e712271c17-2052164901.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Port:                     <unset>  8080/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31545/TCP
Endpoints:                100.96.0.14:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:
  Type    Reason                Age   From                Message
  ----    ------                ----  ----                -------
  Normal  EnsuringLoadBalancer  45s   service-controller  Ensuring load balancer
  Normal  EnsuredLoadBalancer   43s   service-controller  Ensured load balancer
```

I was expecting to see at least tomcats landing page which I get if I run this image in docker.

What am I missing?

Comment: can you please provide output for `kubectl describe service my-service`?

Comment: @Const added the description

Comment: Does "don't get any response" mean it times out, is 404, is refused, other? If it times out, for sure check the security groups for that ELB

Comment: May the problem with your firewall on AWS? Did you allow the connection to your port 80 or 8080?

Comment: Are your nodes created with a public IP from AWS? If you are trying to hit the cluster from the same vpc, I believe you have issues with security groups. Else, you can try creating your nodes public and see for a poc.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your manifests (if executed on docker edge as is they run fine without modifications and tomcat page is displayed correctly). Service description indicate that http://a5c67f4526eb811e881a24e712271c17-2052164901.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com:8080 should be available, providing that 8080 is opened on load balancer security group and tomcat pod is up and running. What do you get when you try to land there? Timeout or connection error? Can you wget from another container and service?